# Aligning Prepend/Append textboxes in bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, tablecell

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to line up to 2 prepend and appended text boxes in a table cell. Has anyone successfully done this? i've messed with display, float, and width options...

```
<td class="success">
<div class="input-prepend">
   <span class="add-on"> USD $ </span>
    <input type="text" class="input-small pi-dollarchange">
 </div>
 <div class="input-append">
     <input type="text" class="input-small pi-perchange">
    <span class="add-on"> % </span>
  </div>
  </td>
```

Comment: Why are they in a table cell? Do you have a form tag round the table?

Comment: Both containing DIVs would have to be floated left I guess to line them up horizontally. And obviously the table cell would need to have enough width to accommodate both inputs. Generally you shouldn't use tables for layout unless it's tabular date you're displaying.

Answer (score 0):

JSfiddle[Jsfiddle with example](http://jsfiddle.net/shail/WcTgk/5/)

To align inputs and labels correctly do the following:-
 1. Wrap labels and controls in `.control-group`.
 2. Add `.control-label` to the label
 3. Wrap any associated controls in `.controls` for proper alignment.

```
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="inputDollars">Dollars</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <div class="input-prepend"> <span class="add-on"> USD $ </span>

            <input type="text" class="input-small pi-dollarchange"
            placeholder="dollar">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="inputPercentage">Percentage</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <div class="input-append">
            <input class="span2 pi-perchange" id="appendedInput" type="text" placeholder="percentage"> <span class="add-on"> % </span>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```